# MySQL w/ Cloudera crashes after reboot

Tags: mysql

After the head node running Rocks Cluster on CentOS 6.8 restarted MySQL dies with the below errors. Could it really be I "*hit a bug*"?

```
161109 13:58:40 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
18:58:40 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=33554432
read_buffer_size=2097152
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=25
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 289028 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x1b5bc40
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7ffdb526bd50 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/libexec/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x29) [0x8509f9]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x483) [0x6a3f13]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x33c3e0f7e0]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(ha_resolve_by_name(THD*, st_mysql_lex_string const*)+0x81) [0x698831]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(open_table_def(THD*, st_table_share*, unsigned int)+0xe0a) [0x610ada]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(get_table_share(THD*, TABLE_LIST*, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int*)+0x20b) [0x6042eb]
/usr/libexec/mysqld() [0x608eaa]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(open_table(THD*, TABLE_LIST*, st_mem_root*, bool*, unsigned int)+0x7a1) [0x60ac01]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(open_tables(THD*, TABLE_LIST**, unsigned int*, unsigned int)+0x5d0) [0x60b7d0]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(open_and_lock_tables_derived(THD*, TABLE_LIST*, bool)+0x6a) [0x60b9da]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(plugin_init(int*, char**, int)+0x622) [0x7197e2]
/usr/libexec/mysqld() [0x5bf202]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(main+0x1b3) [0x5c1af3]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x33c361ed1d]
/usr/libexec/mysqld() [0x5098f9]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 0
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
161109 13:58:40 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Here is the config file:

```
cat /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
# symbolic-links=0

key_buffer              = 16M
key_buffer_size         = 32M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 256K
thread_cache_size       = 64
query_cache_limit       = 8M
query_cache_size        = 64M
query_cache_type        = 1
# Important: see Configuring the Databases and Setting max_connections
max_connections         = 25

# log-bin should be on a disk with enough free space
log-bin=/export/home/cloudera-scm/logs/mysql_binary_log
#log-bin-index=/export/home/cloudera-scm/logs/mysql_binary_log.index

# For MySQL version 5.1.8 or later. Comment out binlog_format for older versions.
binlog_format           = mixed

read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
sort_buffer_size = 8M
join_buffer_size = 8M

# InnoDB settings
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 64M
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 4G
innodb_thread_concurrency       = 8
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size = 512M

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Version:

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1